# define build sources list in external file

Tags: gruntjs

I am a gruntjs newbie and am trying to write a build for JS frontend. A requirement is set so that all the source files that enter the build process (concatenation, minification) must be defined in an external file:

```
|-config
  |- js.json
|-src
  |- js
     |- a.js
     |- b.js
|- Gruntfile.js
|- package.json
```

I have simplified the project structure to illustrate the problem. The `config/js.json` looks like this:

```
[
   "<%=js_dir%>/a.js",
   "<%=js_dir%>/b.js"
]
```

`Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        "options": {"separator": ";"},
        "build": {
            "src": "<%= grunt.template.process(grunt.file.read('./config/js.json'),{data: {js_dir: './src/js'}})%>"
                    ,
            "dest": "build/app.js"
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
};
```

When I run it an empty output file is made, because the source list is empty:

```
...
Reading ./config/js.json...OK
Files: [no src] -> build/app.js
Reading ./config/js.json...OK
Writing out...OK
Writing build/app.js...OK
File "build/app.js" created.

Done, without errors.
```

To verify my logic I dumped the processed sources list by changing the `src` property like this:

```
"src": "<%= grunt.file.write('out',grunt.template.process(grunt.file.read('./config/js.json'),{data: {js_dir: './src/js'}}))%>"
```

The contents of the `out` file show that template processing logic is valid:

```
[
   ".src/js/a.js",
   ".src/js/b.js"
]
```

Since the `src` property [accepts a hardcoded JSON array of source files](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#compact-format) my guess is that the binding of the sources list is done before the templating is done.

The gruntjs verbose output shows the reading of `config/js.json` before and after the concatenation which confuses me.

I tried rewriting the `config/js.json` file so that all the JSON array fits in one line but to no avail.

If this can be done, please tell me how. If it can't be done please tell me why.

My environment:

- grunt: grunt-cli v0.1.9, grunt v0.4.1
- nodejs: v0.11.6-pre
- os: Linux localhost 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Grunt config will process templates as the config is read. So you dont need an additional `grunt.template.process`. Assuming `config/js.json` is valid JSON just do this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    js_dir: 'src/js',
    concat: {
        options: {separator: ";"},
        build: {
            src: require('./config/js.json'),
            dest: "build/app.js"
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
};
```

Always remember Gruntfiles are JavaScript and not JSON.